# Is it possible to revalidate a expired access token without using any facebook sdk?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

I use c++ and libcurl to interact with face book.
I'm make a native windows application,so I can't use any facebook sdk.
Can I handle expired/invalidate access token by using graph api?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless the user has de-authorized your ap.

read this [Facebook: How-To: Handle expired access tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/)

Just call the graph api

this is what happens in php, but i think you can translate it fairly easy

```
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
  . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
  . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
  . "&code=" . $code . "&display=popup";
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$access_token = $params['access_token'];
```